# Is there any way to register tenant specific controller in asp.net core using autofac?

Tags: autofac, multi-tenant

I am working on an application built on asp.net core 3.1 + Autofac as DI. Now i want to implement multi tenant feature. I am able to register tenant specific services and it is working as expected.

What i want to achieve is to register tenant specific controller to override default controller registered in main/application level container.

I have registered custom IApplicationFeatureProvider to register only main controllers.

here is the code.

```
//Startup.cs
public class StartUp
{
  void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
  {
    services.AddControllers().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
    {
      apm.FeatureProviders.RemoveAt(0); //remove default controller feature provider
      apm.FeatureProviders.Add(new MyControllerFeatureProvider()); //register custom provider
    }).AddControllersAsServices();
    services.AddAutofacMultitenantRequestServices();
    //rest of the configuration
  }

  public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    //registration of global or main services
    builder.RegisterType<MyTenantIdentificationStrategy>()
   .As<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>().SingleInstance(); //Get Tenant from request header
    builder.Register(container =>
    {
      ITenantIdentificationStrategy strategy = 
      container.Resolve<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>();
      // tenant resolution code
      return new Tenant();
     }).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
  }

  public static MultitenantContainer ConfigureMultitenantContainer(IContainer container)
  {
      var strategy <-- resolved from container
      MultitenantContainer mtc = new MultitenantContainer(strategy, container);
      mtc.ConfigureTenant(1, cb => {
       cb.RegisterType<IP.Controllers.Extended.HomeController>).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    });
    return mtc;
  }
}

//HomeController.cs
namespace IP.Controllers 
{
  [Route("[controller]")]
  public class HomeController : ControllerBase
  {
  }

  [Route("Get")
  public IActionResult Get()
  {
    return new JsonResult(new {Main = true});
  }
}

//HomeController1.cs
namespace IP.Controllers.Extended <-- different namespace
{
[Route("[controller]")]
  public class HomeController : ControllerBase
  {
  }

  [Route("Get")
  public IActionResult Get()
  {
    return new JsonResult(new {Main = false});
  }
}

//program.cs
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacMultitenantServiceProviderFactory(Startup.ConfigureMultitenantContainer))
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }

http://localhost:8082/Home/Get [Without tenantid in header]
http://localhost:8082/Home/Get [Without tenantid=1 in header]
```

In both case main home controller is resolved not tenant specific..

Any help well be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is going to have to do with routing as much as type resolution. If routing is pointing at the original type it won't try to resolve anything else.

Comment: @Travis, Yes you are right. Controller selection is not handled by Autofac.

First i remove custom application feature provider. Now framework throws multiple match found exception. I looked into stack trace and found that, EndPointResolver implementation is throwing ambiguity exception. I just replace EndPointResolver with my custom implementation and resolve ambiguity..

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my own question,

Routing and controller selection is handled Asp.Net Core not by Autofac.

I am registering tenant specific controllers in ConfigureTenant method. Asp.Net Core Framework is not aware about these controllers. So for given route framework always selects registered controller not extended one registered in ConfigureTenant method.

So first i have removed custom application feature provider. Now all controllers in current assembly are registered. Then removed separate registration of controllers from ConfigureTenant method. Now framework throws ambiguity exception because there are two controllers with same route.

From stack trace, i found that EndPointResolver implementation is throwing ambiguity exception. Since we can provide our own implementation for EndPointResolver, i create custom EndPointResolver and register it.

Now during route selection, if there is ambiguity while selecting controller, i just retrieve tenant information from request header and based on Tanent i am handling ambiguity exception.

I am not sure if it is the correct approach but now i am able to register controller with same name [same Route] in different namespace/assembly.